# What is the most elegant way to load a string array into a List<int>?

Tags: c#, list, initialization

Consider an array of strings containing numerical values:

```
string[] intArray = {"25", "65" , "0"};
```

What is the most elegant way to load the numbers into a `List<int>` without using a `for` or `while` to iterate over the `intArray`?

Comment: `var list = intArray.ToList();`...?

Comment: May I ask why you have a string array of textual numbers if you really want it as integers? Always, when people do this I have to ask: What is the chance of that array containing something that isn't a number? And if the chance is 0, why not make it a numeric array instead?

Comment: The editor removed my <int> from the question!! Its still in the title though.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Its being read from a CSV file.

Comment: Why not get a real CSV parser library then, instead of a simplified LINQish solution that people present here? If it's a CSV file, at one point or another you'll encounter a file that is badly formatted, contains dot instead of commas for decimal points (or vice versa), have an extra column or row with things that aren't a number, and so on. All of which your program should deal with gracefully.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: To avoid complicating the question unnecessarily, lets assume the validity of the string is taken care of.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) method

```
List<int> intList = intArray.Select(str => int.Parse(str)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 18):

(addition to Dmitry's answer)
You can get rid of lambda, because that method already has the right signature:

```
List<int> intList = intArray.Select(Int32.Parse).ToList();
```

Comment: Note that doing this will allocate a new delegate every time whereas Dmitry's will use a cached one.

Comment: @CoryNelson are you sure?

Comment: Yes, thought this is more an implementation detail than something you can count on always being the case. Maybe Mono does it differently?

Comment: @CoryNelson Do you know of any documentation that says using a lambda rather than a method group caches a delegate?

Comment: @PeterMajeed Here is nice blog post that explains it well
http://blog.filipekberg.se/2013/02/15/optimize-your-delegate-usage/

Comment: @SargeBorsch I agree, I hope they will [fix it](http://blog.filipekberg.se/2013/02/15/optimize-your-delegate-usage/#comment-5776) in Roslyn soon

Comment: @CichyK24 That is only relevant if the delegate is referenced inside a loop. Here, the delegate object is created once and the reference is copied into a parameter. Unless the entire Select/ToList statement is in a loop, there shouldn't be any performance disadvantage to this approach.

Answer (score 3):

Just call `Select()`:

```
using System.Linq;

var list = intArray.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x));
```

PS: Your question changed after I initially answered.

Answer (score 2):

This is the way to do it..

```
string[] intArray = { "25", "65", "0" };
List<int> intList = new List<int>(Array.ConvertAll(intArray, s => int.Parse(s)));
```

**OR**

```
 string[] intArray = { "25", "65", "0" };
 List<int> intList = new List<int>(intArray.Select(int.Parse).ToArray());
```

**OR**

```
 string[] intArray = { "25", "65", "0" };
 List<int> intList = new List<int>(Array.ConvertAll(intArray, int.Parse));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised that no one had mentioned [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx)

```
string[] intArray = { "25", "65", "0" };
int tempNumber;
List<int> list = intArray.Select(r => int.TryParse(r, out tempNumber) 
                                     ? tempNumber : -1)
                     .ToList();
```

This would deal with invalid inputs and returns `-1` as the value. *(It can be any number specifying an error or `0`)*

If the `intArray` will only contain parse able integers then following would do the work:

```
List<int> list = intArray.Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```